# How to reverse the link list i have created in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I have created a linked list but couldn't think of how to reverse the same. I know the algo but i think i have made a mistake in creating the list. What could be the change in reverse function so that it work.
Following is the code:

```
typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} node;
node* head;
int count;
void insertAtBegin(int value){
    if(head==NULL){
        head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        head->data = 0;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->next = head->next;
    head->next = newNode;
    count++;
}

void display(){
    node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp = head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL){
        printf("%d\t",temp->next->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void reverse(){
    node *p, *q, *r;

    p = q = r = head;
    p = p->next->next;
    q = q->next;
    r->next = NULL;
    q->next = r;

    while (p != NULL){
        r = q;
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
        q->next = r;
    }
    head = q;
}

void main(){
    insertAtBegin(5);
    insertAtBegin(6);
    display();
    reverse();
    display();
    printf("\nSize of linked list is %d",count);
}
```

Comment: `node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp = head;` is a memory leak. Why do you alloc a node when you want to display them?

Comment: Start coding yourself and then ask questions if you have difficulties.

Comment: @mch ok i didn't have the idea..thanks but that would probably not solve my problem of reversing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the following list:

```
head = n0
n0 -> ... -> A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> ... -> nN -> NULL
```

That you want to reverse to:

```
head = nN
nN -> ... -> E -> D -> C -> B -> A -> ... -> n0 -> NULL
```

Now, let's consider the case when the beginning of the list is already reversed and that you're dealing with the node `C`. Your list at that time is:

```
head = B
B -> A -> ... -> n0-> NULL
tmpHead  = C
C -> D -> E ... -> nN -> NULL
```

Where `tmpHead` is a temporary variable that allow you to not lose a reference to `C` (as `B.next` is now pointing to `A`) You want to:

1. connect `B` to `C` so that `B` comes after `C`
2. Set head to `C`, the new head of the reversed list
3. keep `D` in the temporary variable `tmpHead`, so that you can still access it

Reversing then becomes:

```
node * tmp   = tmpHead.next;  // 3. part 1
tmpHead.next = head;          // 1.
head         = tmpHead;       // 2.
tmpHead      = tmp;           // 3. part 2
```

The stop condition is quite obvious: you have to stop when you reached the end of the list, so, when `tmpHead` is `NULL`. As to the initialization, as `head` as to point to the reversed part and `tmpHead` to the non reversed one. So `tmpHead` has to be set to `head` and `head` to `NULL`.

At the end, you get the following function which take a pointer to the first node of your list as input parameter

```
void reverse(node ** head)
{
  node * tmpHead = (* head);
  (* head)       = NULL;

  while(tmpHead)
  {
    node * tmp    = tmpHead->next;
    tmpHead->next = (* head);
    (* head)      = tmpHead;
    tmpHead       = tmp;
  }
}
```

Note that there's a "problem" with the way you insert a new node at the beginning of your list : you always keep a "phantom" node with data set to `0` and that you call `head`. So, the first real node of the list, as I defined it, is your `head->next`. Which means you have to call the `reverse` function like this : `reverse(& (head->next))` or slightly modify the function.

Also, please note that you shouldn't cast the result of a malloc. [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: I think you need to replace `head` with `*head` throughout the body of your `reverse` function.